# Elastic Search way to hide document form search till end of import process

Tags: elasticsearch

I am wondering if there is any way to "hide" documents from search routine in following case:

1. Import process are run daily.
2. Import process are indexing documents to Elastic Search via multiple calls to `_bulk`
3. While import process is running I do not what just imported documents where able for getting via `_search`.

Does Elastic search have some kind of transaction support - no index document will be available till transactions is committed?

I expect number of documents being indexed in one import process to be quite numerous. So I cannot do one `_bulk` call.

I tried `index.refresh_interval` index setting and calling `_refresh` at the end of import process. But it does not helped much - documents became searchable in the middle of import process.

Comment: Is it a single node setup or have you setup sharding?

Comment: I am using 8 shards for this index

Comment: > I tried index.refresh_interval index setting (...) but it does not helped much - documents became searchable in the middle of import process. -- You might have had an error in the configuration -- when you set `refresh_interval:"-1"`, no new documents should be visible for searches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elasticsearch doesn't support transaction. You will need to handle this functionality on the client side. If you are only adding documents (no updates), you can associate a batch id with each record and filter out all records with batch id >= the currently running batch. At the end of the batch when you want to make new records available you can update the filter to include just finished batch id. You can associate this filter with an alias, which will make the switch transparent for searchers. This approach is not going to work in case of updates though.